# Tying to change key values inside an object but its adding double values

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tying to change key values inside an object but its adding double values or its adding all values at once. Every name must get an value which in this case is a language slug. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
// the data
const routesObj = [
    { name: 'dashboard.index' },
    { name: 'settings.index' },
    { name: 'settings.general' },
    { ... }
]
// end results (how i want it to be)
[
    {  
        nl: {
            routes: [
                {
                    name: 'nl.dashboard.index'
                },
                {
                    name: 'nl.dashboard.index'
                },
                {
                    name: 'nl.settings.general'
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {  
        en: {
            routes: [
                {
                    name: 'en.dashboard.index'
                },
                {
                    name: 'en.dashboard.index'
                },
                {
                    name: 'en.settings.general'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
// how its working now(not good)
[
    {  
        nl: {
            routes: [
                {
                    name: 'en.nl.dashboard.index'//adding both languages
                },
                ...
            ]
        }
    },
    ...
]

const routeBuilder = (routes, languages) => {
    let newRoutes = []
    languages.forEach(function(lang){
        Object.keys(routes).forEach(function(key){ 
            routes[key]['name'] = lang+'.'+routes[key]['name']
        });   
        newRoutes[lang] = {routes};       
    });
    return newRoutes
}

routeBuilder(routesObj, ['nl','en'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```js
Object.keys(routes).forEach(function(key){ 
  routes[key]['name'] = lang+'.'+routes[key]['name']
});
newRoutes[lang] = {routes};
```

1. `routes` is a reference to `routesObj`, so the code above modifies the original object in each `languages.forEach` iteration. The solution is to clone `routes` so that each iteration has a unique copy.
2. `newRoutes` is an array, but it's being used like an object in `newRoutes[lang]`. To insert an object into the `newRoutes` array, use `Array.prototype.push`.

```js
const routesObj = [
    { name: 'dashboard.index' },
    { name: 'settings.index' },
    { name: 'settings.general' },
]

const routeBuilder = (routes, languages) => {
  const newRoutes = []
  languages.forEach(function(lang) {

  routes = routesObj.map(x => ({...x})); // 1️⃣

  Object.keys(routes).forEach(function(key){ 
      routes[key]['name'] = lang+'.'+routes[key]['name']
    });   
    newRoutes.push({ [lang]: { routes } }); // 2️⃣
  })
  
  return newRoutes;
}

const routes = routeBuilder(routesObj, ['nl','en'])

console.log(routes)
```

Alternatively, use nested `Array.prototoype.map`s:

```js
const routesObj = [
    { name: 'dashboard.index' },
    { name: 'settings.index' },
    { name: 'settings.general' },
]

const routeBuilder = (routes, languages) => {
  return languages.map(lang => {
    return {
      [lang]: {
        routes: routes.map(route => ({ ...route, name: lang + '.' + route.name })),
      }
    }
  })
}
const routes = routeBuilder(routesObj, ['nl','en'])

console.log(routes)
```